# hibernate, inherit all entities from a @MappedSuperClass

Tags: java, hibernate, mappedsuperclass

i want set some fields, like updateDate, createDate and deleteDate, for each my entities, so i thought to inherit my entities from a @MappedSuperClass that contains this properties.

Is this a good pratice?

In what way you work for this kind of request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is what I do. I have a "BasicEntity" abstract class that is the superclass of all my entities and has fields like id, creationDate, uuid and implementations of hashCode and equals etc.